# tcp/ip Connection between android device and labview

Tags: android, tcp, connection, ip, labview

I am trying to do TCP/IP connection between Android and LabView. The LabView master project is working.

I made a design of interface (a couple of text boxes for entering IP address and port number and a button for connection). Port number and IP address will be arranged user input. I'm little confused. I have no idea what i have to use or which code structures should be used.

May you share your advice? I am using Android Studio.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @stefanobaghino thank you

Comment: What is you specific and concrete question?

Comment: @D.J. Klomp Actually I want to send data from a labview to an android device. The labview is connected to wifi which is connected to modem. Android device will also connected to same router through WI-FI. Can you please suggest some links or tutorial from where i can get idea how to establish communication between labview an the android device to send and receive data through WI-FI . –

Comment: Sorry, this site isn't the place for 'please suggest a tutorial for x' questions. You can find examples of TCP/IP communication in the examples installed with LabVIEW; you might find someone willing to help on the National Instruments discussion boards.

Answer (score 0):

A well explained tutorial for TCP server and Client in android 
https://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2012/07/20/android-tcp-connection-tutorial/

Comment: thanks but Can you share another link? I researched but going back to beginning.